# How to change the version of WPF unless checking the registry?

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, web

i set `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` 
when WPF pop up the browser version worked as IE7. ( this PC has IE EDGE & 11)
is there any way to solve this while avoiding registry?

Comment: If you are on Windows 10 build 17110 or later and use .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later, you could use the new [WebView control](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/#lsqYlL6Yzo1DcAaX.97).

Comment: i will try thanks you !